# Create numpy array with conditional step

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im trying to convert this code into one-liner function using lambda and numpy, the function should return numpy array, but i dont know how to save the step value for each iteration

```
import random

def generate_array(n: int):
    step = 1
    arr = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        step = step + 1 if random.choice([True, False]) else step - 1 
        arr .append(step)

    return arr

generate_array(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create the difference array using `np.random.choice`, and then sum each item up cumulatively using `np.cumsum()`:

```
np.cumsum(np.random.choice([1, -1], size=10))
```

Comment: There is no need for a list comprehension here